# Get visible location of SpriteKit node after parent rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation, sprite-kit

I am using Sprite Kit (uh, perhaps "learning" is more apropos). I have a square game board:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
| 0,2 | 1,2 | 2,2 |
+-----+-----+-----+
| 0,1 | 1,1 | 2,1 |
+-----+-----+-----+
| 0,0 | 1,0 | 2,0 |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

During testing I am adding a sprite to board position 2,0.  I then rotate the board 90 degrees counter-clockwise leaving the sprite - visually - in position 2,2.  Of course, since the position of sprites aren't modified by rotation the actual x,y coords don't change.  My algorithms, etc. are geared around 'visual' board positions saving me from needing to write code for all 4 rotation angles.  So, I know internally that the sprite at 2,0 moved to 2,2 (visually); and I now need to work with "the sprite seen at board position 2,2".  How do I get hold of the 'visual' x,y coords of the sprite?  I've tried:

```
[_board convertPoint:p toNode:self];
[_board convertPoint:p toNode:self.view];     // didn't expect this to work
```

'p' is a CGPoint that I've calculated from board position 2,2.  This isn't a code question - it's more of a noobie "how do I do this" question.

Answer (score 0):

To get an `SKNode`'s *visual position*, you'd want to convert its `.position` in its `.parent`'s coordinate system to its `.scene`'s coordinate system:

```
CGPoint vPos = [node.parent convertPoint:node.position toNode:node.scene];
```

It looks like the first attempt you made (`[_board convertPoint:p toNode:self]`) should work, as long as:

1. `p` is a valid point inside the node you're looking for in `_board`'s coordinate system.
2. That code is called from your `SKScene` so that `self` references the scene the node is in.

Comment: Does convertPoint:toNode only work with immediate parents? if so, that would explain some issues I had with using it.

Comment: @Rudi it should work between any two nodes in the scene's node tree. I'm not sure why I had originally put that constraint in my answer; I edited it out.