# SpriteKit SKNode visual position in parent(s) after parent(s) are rotated?

Tags: sprite-kit, sknode

I have following hierarchy:

Scene -> Root node -> NodeA -> NodeB (anchor node that's rotated) -> NodeC

how can I figure out visual position of NodeC in Root node coordinate space?

I've tried several variants with convertPoint:toNode: and convertPoint:fromNode: but numbers i'm getting don't match.

I've also looked at [Get visible location of SpriteKit node after parent rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25224319/get-visible-location-of-spritekit-node-after-parent-rotation), which seems to be close to my issue, but no luck there either.

Comment: What variants did you try, what results did you get, and what results did you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Found what I was missing - convertToPoint needs to be called from the node in which final CGPoint value will be represented in. So, this works:

```
// point is CGPointZero because it is center of NodeC

let point = rootNode.convertPoint(CGPointZero, fromNode: NodeC) as CGPoint!
```